# Woocommerce Customer API

Tags: next.js13, woocommerce-rest-api

Since WooCommerce does not expose an API for Logging in customers using user credentials, I utilized a plugin that returns the User ID from the function that calls the first API.
The id returned is used to query the WooCommerce customers api and return the customer by id.

The issue now is that the WooCommerce customer endpoint does not return the correct customer data.

Plugins utilized: JWT Authentication for WP-API

I Used useEffect hook to run the second function that uses the id returned to call the WooCommerce API.

Comment: What are you trying to do and what is the general architecture? We need a bit more context to help you.

Comment: The architecture simple - WordPress - Woocommerce backend, next js frontend.